# Thunderbird won't start - addon error?

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird won't open. I've uninstalled it and installed it again but it did not work.

Is it an addon that bothers it?

Code

```
AdapterDeviceID: 0x0a16
AdapterVendorID: 0x8086
Add-ons: contacttabs%40janek.org:2.0.10,mailmerge%40example.net:3.8.0,markdown-here%40adam.pritchard:2.11.0,sendlater3%40kamens.us:4.2.4,thunderlink%40mozilla.org:1.2.1,%7B19503e42-ca3c-4c27-b1e2-9cdb2170ee34%7D:1.5.6.3,%7BBDD92442-0534-4D6F-A966-BAB7D561D781%7D:0.7.12,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:31.0,gconversation%40xulforum.org:2.7
AvailablePageFile: 9528619008
AvailablePhysicalMemory: 4113940480
AvailableVirtualMemory: 3869913088
BIOS_Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
BlockedDllList: 
BreakpadReserveAddress: 46333952
BreakpadReserveSize: 41943040
BuildID: 20140717165725
CrashTime: 1408368677
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 00000000f0de0000
FramePoisonSize: 65536
InstallTime: 1408355478
Notes: AdapterVendorID: 0x8086, AdapterDeviceID: 0x0a16, AdapterSubsysID: 00051179, AdapterDriverVersion: 10.18.10.3412
D2D? D2D+ DWrite? DWrite+ D3D10 Layers? D3D10 Layers+ 
ProductID: {3550f703-e582-4d05-9a08-453d09bdfdc6}
ProductName: Thunderbird
ReleaseChannel: release
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 51
StartupTime: 1408368661
SystemMemoryUsePercentage: 51
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
TotalPageFile: 17021378560
TotalPhysicalMemory: 8511643648
TotalVirtualMemory: 4294836224
URL: 
Vendor: 
Version: 31.0
Winsock_LSP: MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP] : 2 : 1 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IP] : 2 : 2 :  
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IP] : 2 : 3 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IPv6] : 2 : 1 :  
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IPv6] : 2 : 2 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IPv6] : 2 : 3 :  
 RSVP TCPv6 Service Provider : 2 : 1 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 RSVP TCP Service Provider : 2 : 1 :  
 RSVP UDPv6 Service Provider : 2 : 2 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 RSVP UDP Service Provider : 2 : 2 : 
useragent_locale: en-US

Den här rapporten innehåller också teknisk information om programförhållandena vid kraschen.
```

Comment: Are you able to [start Thunderbird in Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/safe-mode)?

Comment: No. Tried to check box 1. Then box 1 and box 2. Did not help.

Comment: Is Thunderbird installed for all users? Do you get the same issue if you use a different user account?